# how do i add page title to hyperlink

Tags: wordpress, url, hyperlink

I'm modifiying a page template on wordpress. I chose to use a script so that the referrer link would show on hover, and I got it to work fine, until I decided to add the page title to the link. Then things stopped working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="<?php echo $container;?>">
  <div class="media-back-button">
    <script><?php $back_title = get_the _title(); ?>
      document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Back To Media - ' + $back_title +'</a>');
    </script>
</div>

<!-- remaining page content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using php in javascript. 
The correct is:

```
<div class="<?php echo $container;?>">
  <div class="media-back-button">
    <script>
      var back_title = "<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"; // use declaration in javascript with echo of php
      document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Back To Media - ' + back_title +'</a>'); 
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using php code in javascript code. Please use following code

```
<div class="<?php echo $container;?>">
    <div class="media-back-button">
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            var back_title = "<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>"; // current page/post title
            document.write('<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Back To Media - ' + back_title +'</a>'); 
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for this. Now I know!